# How to format linux

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, windows-10, format

I have a Dell Inspiron 7567 (128 SSD + 1TB HDD) with pre-installed ubuntu on the SSD.
I want to format the SSD so that I can install Windows on SSD and then reinstall Ubuntu.

How can I format the SSD ?

Comment: You can use a windows installation media, boot from the media and format the SSD during windows installation process.

Answer (score 3):

When you start installing Windows, you can format the SSD from there and install Windows on it. There is no need to format the SSD before installing Windows.